# Select tag php generated code requires javascript interaction

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I am working on a piece of javascript to copy a link plus the option the user has selected within the select tag.

The variable I assign in the javascript remains undefined. Is there a way to make this code work? I do not wish to use the ID attribute with a loop unless this can be applied into my PHP script (in which I echo the select tags, because I'm showing database results, whenever a result is shown, it will also show a select tag). This link shows a simple example of what I made so far: http://jsfiddle.net/b31au78v/

Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hank</td>
        <td>
            <select onChange="getValue()" class="ddlEval">
                <option>Select an option...</option>
                <option val="gender.php?=male">Male</option>
                <option val="gender.php?=female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jeff</td>
        <td>
            <select onChange="getValue()" class="ddleval">
                <option>Select an option...</option>
                <option val="gender.php?=male">Male</option>
                <option val="gender.php?=female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function getValue() {
    optVal = this.value;
    if(optVal != "Select an option...")
    {
    window.prompt("This is the link that's going to be coppied: ", "localhost:8080/" + optVal);
    }
}
</script>
```

I guess I need to replace "this" with something else, but it is only to show what I actually want to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
var optVal = selectTag.options[selectTag.selectedIndex].value;
```

In your case ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1ac6c75/2/)):

```
<script>
    function getValue(s) {
    optVal = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
    if(optVal != "Select an option...")
    {
    window.prompt("This is: ", "localhost:8080/gender.php?=" + optVal);
    }
}
</script>
```

While changing the onChange event code:

```
        <select onChange="getValue(this)"...
```

Please notice that you should also pass the id/name of the member,
so when someone changes the first member's gender it won't conflict with the second one.

Comment: No problem, just update me if it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

There's no attribute `val` it should be [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value):

```
<option value="none">Select an option …</option>
<option value="gender.php?=male">Male</option>
```

**Note**: If you don't have an attribute `value` the value of the element will be the *text* of the `option`-element selected instead.

---

`this` in your function has a different scope, so it's not aware of a property called `this.value`. You can however pass the element into the function, like:

```
<select onchange="getValue(this);"></select>
```

Then you can get its value like:

```
function getValue(e) {
    var optVal = e.value;
    if ('none' != optVal) {
        window.prompt("This is the link that's going to be coppied: ", "localhost:8080/" + optVal);
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/n735mrt1/)